# Handle querystring coontaining [] in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, query-string

What is the best way to handle the queries[search] and sorts[Driver1] parameters in the following querystring in asp.net?

```
?queries[search]=greenock&id=20&sorts[Driver1]=1
```

I tried using this model but only id was bound:

```
public class ICRSRequestModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public ICollection<string> Sorts { get; set; }
    public ICollection<string> Queries { get; set; }
}
```

I don't have the option of changing the requesting application unfortunately, and the string contained inside [] could be any unknown value.

Comment: Perhaps helpful: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the property is

```
public ICollection<string> Queries { get; set; }
```

Then the query string would need to be

```
?queries[0]=greenock
```

you would need to change the property to

```
public Dictionary<string, string> Queries { get; set; }
```

so that the query string could be

```
?queries[search]=greenock
```

The key will be "search" and the value will be "greenock"

Note this will only work for a single `queries` value. `?queries[search]=greenock?queries[anotherKey]=anotherValue` will not work

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, not got 50 rep points yet else I would have commented with this probably useless comment, but here goes..

I'm sure there's a better way using MVC bindings but if all else fails it might be worth taking the QueryString from the Server.Request object and splitting the string up to extract the information you want. You can get them in to a keyvaluepair collection using the code I had lying around in a project, I'm sure it can be manipulated for your needs.

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (string part in queryString.Split(new char[] { '&' }))
{
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(part))
   {
       string[] strArray = part.Split(new char[] { '=' });
       if (strArray.Length == 2)
       {
           dictionary[strArray[0]] = strArray[1];
       }
       else
       {
           dictionary[part] = null;
       }
   }
}
```